# How to parse a JSX file and convert to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, file, jsx, reader

I want to generate a json object from a JSX file like this:

index.js

```
  return (
          <h1  cmsContent = {{
              id:'h1',
              type: 'Text'}}>
          </h1>    
          <div cmsContent = {{
                id:'blocks',
                type: 'ManyReferences',
                referenceTime: 2}}>
            {this.state.cmsContent.blocks.map( block => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div cmsContent= {{
                    id:'title',
                    type: 'Text'}}
                  ></div>
                  <p cmsContent= {{
                    id:'description',
                    type: 'Text'}} ></p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          <h2 cmsContent = {{
            id:'h2',
            type: 'Text'}} ></h2>
);
```

json object generated from file:

```
 const json = { fields: [
    {
      id: 'h1',
      required: true,
      type: 'Text'
    },
    {
        blocks: [{ 
            fields : [ 
                  { id: 'title1', required: true, type:'Text' },
                  { id: 'description1', required: true, type:'Text' }
            ] },
            fields : [ 
                  { id: 'title2', required: true, type:'Text' },
                  { id: 'description2', required: true, type:'Text' }
            ] }
    },
    {
      id: 'h2',
      required: true,
      type: 'Text'
    }
  ]
```

Does anyone have an idea to generate this json object?
I use react js.
What is the best to generate this json object?

Comment: What did you try by now?

Comment: Are you sure that index.js is javascript? Doesn't look like legal JavaScript to me, more like react a JSX file.

Comment: There is not going to be any simple generalized way to do this. You will need a parser that fully understands the input file format.

Comment: yes it's a jsx file

Comment: So your question is really how do I parse a JSX file. The answer is use the react compiler. But you surely don't actually want to do that. I think you should take a different approach. Where does the JSX file come from and how does the data get into it. Is it hard coded or is a service that is generating the JSX file?

Comment: I want to generate the json by launching a test for example. My approach is to use jest and  I will parse the snapshot to generate the json. What do you think @bhspencer ?

Comment: I am not sure how Jest helps you here. How do you plan to parse the snapshot?